# Yang-Mills constraints and Poisson brackets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, yang-mills, constrained-dynamics, dirac-delta-distributions, poisson-brackets

Let's have constraints for Yang-Mills theory:
$$
\varphi_{a} = \partial_{i}\pi^{i}_{a} - f_{abc}\pi^{b}_{i}A^{c}_{i}.
$$
I have [read](http://ocw.u-tokyo.ac.jp/lecture_files/sci_03/12/notes/en/ooguri12.pdf) the statement that
$$
\tag 1 [\varphi_{a}(\mathbf x), \varphi_{b}(\mathbf y )] = f_{abc}\varphi^{c}(\mathbf x) \delta (\mathbf x - \mathbf y).
$$
$(1)$ can be computed by using canonical Poisson brackets
$$
[A_{a}^{i}(\mathbf x ), \pi_{b}^{j}(\mathbf y )] = \delta_{ab}\delta^{ij}\delta (\mathbf x - \mathbf y ), \quad [\pi_{a}^{i}(\mathbf x ), \pi_{b}^{j}(\mathbf y )]  = [A_{a}^{i}(\mathbf x ), A_{b}^{j}(\mathbf y )]  = 0.
$$
But I can't get $(1)$. The problem is in two summands which have the form
$$
\tag 2 -\varepsilon_{klm}[\partial_{i}\pi^{i}_{a}(\mathbf x ), A_{m}^{j}(\mathbf y )]\pi_{l}^{j}(\mathbf y) = -\varepsilon_{kla}\pi_{l}^{i}(\mathbf y)\partial_{i}^{\mathbf x}\delta (x - y) = -\varepsilon_{kla}\pi_{l}^{i}(\mathbf y)\partial_{i}^{\mathbf y}\delta(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)
$$
For getting $(1)$ I need to move derivative away from delta-function, but it can be done (in my opinion) only if there also is integration of $(2)$ over $x, y$. Where did I make the mistake? How to get $(1)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems OP's question (v4) is related to the proper handling of derivatives of [Dirac delta distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). Reductions are performed with the help of (the appropriate 3D generalizations of) the following formulas:

$$\tag{A} \{\partial_x+\partial_y\}\delta (x-y)~=~ 0,$$

$$\tag{B} \{f(x)-f(y)\}~\delta (x-y)~=~ 0,$$

$$\tag{C}  \{f(y)-f(x)\}~\partial_x \delta (x-y)~=~ \delta  (x-y) ~f^{\prime}(x),$$

which may be derived e.g. using test functions. Pay attention to the non-zero right-hand side of eq. (C), which we suspect is the culprit of OP's question.