# Calculation of the Poisson bracket of a (Classical) Yang-Mills generator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, yang-mills, constrained-dynamics, dirac-delta-distributions, poisson-brackets

This question might be too technical or minute, but I believe someone can give me the right advise.

What I want to calculate is a Poisson bracket algebra of classical YM gauge generators,

\begin{equation}
\{G_a(\vec{x},t),G_b(\vec{y},t) \}=g f_{ab}^{c} G_c(\vec{x},t)\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{y}),
\end{equation} 
where $G_a(\vec{x},t)\equiv (\vec{D}\cdot \vec{E})_a(\vec{x},t) = \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}_{a}-gf_{abc}\vec{A}^{b}\cdot\vec{E}^{c}$ ($f_{abc}$ is the structure constant of the internal symmetry group). Here, $-E_a^i$'s ($=-F_a^{0i})$ ($i=1,2,3$) are the conjugate momenta of $A_a^i$'s, so the Poisson bracket is given by

\begin{equation}
\{A_{i}^a(\vec{x},t),E_{jb}(\vec{y},t)\}=-\delta_{ij}\delta_b^a\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{y}).
\end{equation}
I have obtained all relations between each factor and they fit the result that I was supposed to obtain, except for the one that is $\{\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}_{a}, f_{bcd}\vec{A}^{c}\cdot\vec{E}^{d}\}$. I used the delta function relation

\begin{equation}  
     \delta'(x-y)f(x)=\delta(x-y)f'(x)
\end{equation}

to calculate it, but the result  was $2f_{abc}\partial_iE^i_a(x)\delta^3(x-y)$, which is  twice bigger than the right value, i.e., $f_{abc}\partial_iE^i_a(x)\delta^3(x-y)$.

I guess the difference is from the process when I used the delta function relation, about which I am not sure whether I understand  exactly the real property of it. I think someone who is used to this kind of calculation can give the right answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141501/2451