# Why is the Poisson bracket of the YM Hamiltonian with the secondary constraint zero?

Tags: field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, yang-mills, constrained-dynamics, poisson-brackets

Suppose we have the following Hamiltonian density

$$\mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2}\pi_i^a \pi_i^a + \frac{1}{4}F_{ij}^a F_{ij}^a $$

where

$$F_{ij}^a = \partial_i A_j^a - \partial_j A_i^a + gf^{abc}A_i^b A_j^c$$

is the (non-abelian) field strength tensor. Now I would like to calculate the Poisson bracket of $\mathcal{H}$ with

$$\phi^a := gf^{abc} A_i^b \pi_i^c  + \partial_i \pi_i^a \,,$$

i.e.

$$\{\mathcal{H},\phi_2^a\} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial H}{\partial A_0^d} \frac{\partial \phi^a}{\partial \pi_0^d}}_{=0} - \underbrace{\frac{\partial H}{\partial \pi_0^d} \frac{\partial \phi^a}{\partial A_0^d}}_{=0} + \underbrace{\frac{\partial H}{\partial A_i^d} \frac{\partial \phi_2^a}{\partial \pi_i^{d}}}_{=:P} - \underbrace{\frac{\partial H}{\partial \pi_i^d} \frac{\partial \phi^a}{\partial A_i^{d}}}_{=0}$$

where $H = \int\mathrm{d}^3x\, \mathcal{H}$. Note that these are functional derivatives. If I did not make any mistakes, three of the terms vanish. Now I have problems calculating $P$. I try to sketch my solution:

$$\begin{align}
P &= \frac{1}{4}  \frac{\partial}{\partial A_i^d} \left(F_{jk}^b F_{jk}^b \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial\pi_i^d} \left(gf^{agc} A_l^g \pi_l^c + \partial_l \pi_l^a \right) \\
&=  \left[\frac{1}{2} F_{jk}^b \frac{\partial}{\partial A_i^d}\left(2\partial_j A_k^b + gf^{bef} A_j^e A_k^f\right)\right] \left( gf^{agd}A_i^g - \overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_i} \delta^{ad} \right) \\
&= \left[F_{jk}^b \frac{\partial}{\partial A_i^d}(\partial_j A_k^b)\right] \left(gf^{agd}A_i^g - \overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_i} \delta^{ad}\right) + \left[\frac{1}{2}gf^{bef} F_{jk}^b \frac{\partial}{\partial A_i^d}(A_j^e A_k^f)\right] \left(gf^{agd}A_i^g - \overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_i} \delta^{ad}\right) \\
&= -\partial_j\left[F_{ji}^d \left(gf^{agd}A_i^g - \overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_i} \delta^{ad}\right)\right] + \left[gf^{bde} F_{ij}^b A_j^e\right] \left(gf^{agd}A_i^g - \overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_i} \delta^{ad}\right) \\
&= \underbrace{\partial_i \partial_j F_{ji}^a}_{=0} - gf^{agd} \partial_j\left( F_{ji}^d A_i^g\right) + g^2 f^{bde} f^{agd} F_{ij}^b A_j^e A_i^g - gf^{bae}\partial_i\left(F_{ij}^bA_j^e\right) \\
&= g^2 f^{bde} f^{agd} F_{ij}^b A_j^e A_i^g + 2gf^{abc} \partial_i\left(F_{ij}^b A_j^c\right) \neq 0 \,?
\end{align}$$

I have read in ["Classical and Quantum Dynamics of Constrained Hamiltonian Systems"](https://books.google.de/books?id=CAJ_uwNYiGEC&pg=PA80&hl=de&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Heinz J. Rothe, Klaus D. Rothe (p. 197) that the result should be $\propto f^{abc} F_{ij}^b F_{ij}^c = 0$, where is my mistake?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141501/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic, thank you for the hint. I just checked my calculations again and I just need to be careful when applying integration by parts since not every $A_i$ or $F_{ij}$ depends on the same variable.